# Pandas: matrix correllation for words

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am new in pandas and python. I want to find common words for my data set. e.g i have list of companies ["Microsoft.com", "Microsoft", "Microsoft com", "apple" ...] etc. I have around 1M list of such companies and i want to calculate correlation between them to find the relevance for the words e.g Microsoft.com, Microsoft, Microsoft com there are common words.

This is what i did but its very slow:

```
import hashlib
companies = pd.read_csv('/tmp/companies.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
unique_companies = companies.groupby(['company'])['company'].unique()
df = DataFrame()

for company in unique_companies:
   df[hashlib.md5(company).hexdigest()] = [{'name': company[0], 'code': [ord(c) for c in company[0]]}]

rows = df.unstack()
for company in rows:
   series1 = Series(company['code'])
   for word in rows:
      series2 = Series(word['code'])
      if series1.corr(series2) > 0.8:
        company['match'] = [word['name']]
```

can anyone please guide me how to find matrix correlation for the words ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a corr function that will work for strings - only numerics.

If you can somehow compress your words into meaningful numeric values that preserves the "closeness" of one against another, you might then be able to "corr" them, but other options are available.

Hamming Distance is one (basic) method, but slightly better is calculating the Levenshtein difference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

It's tricky but one way of trying this would be to build a matrix of m x n cells. Where m is the number of unique words in your first wordlist, and n is the number of unique words in the secornd wordlist - then calculate the Hamming, or Levenshtein distances between row/column identifiers.

There are python modules that package up the distance-algorithms for you - 
e.g. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/
Or you could write your own, I think the packaged ones are likely to be faster as they're C'ified.

So, assuming the Levenshtein module (I don't know, as have not used it) provides a function say `getLev (word1, word2)` that generates a numeric score, you should be able to feed in the contents from two wordlists from sources 1 and 2. If you make sure your inputs are already filtered for uniqueness, and maybe sorted alphabetically, that would help too.

Feed them into a matrix generation function.

Here, I've imported numpy as np and am using that module for speed

```
def genLevenshteinMatrix(wordlist1, wordlist2):
    x = len(wordlist1)
    y = len(wordlist1)
    l_matrix = np.zeros(( x, y))
    for i in range( 0 , x ):
        x_word = wordlist1[i]
        for j in range ( 0 , y ):
            y_word = wordlist[j]
            l_matrix[i][j] = getLev ( x_word, y_word )
```

Something like that should allow you to generate a matrix that stores a measure of which words are most like which other words.

Once that's created, you can interrogate it using a function like this:

```
def interrogate_Levenshtein_matrix (ndarray_x, wordlist1, wordlist2, float_threshold):
    l = []
    x = len(ndarray_x) 
    y = len(ndarray_x[0])
    for i in range(0 , x ):
        for j in range(0 , y ):
            if ndarray_x[i][j] >= float_threshold:
                l.append ([(wordlist1[i],wordlist2[j]),ndarray_x[i][j]])
    return l
```

And that will output a list of words that are "close" (i.e. have a lower distance) as measured by the Levenshtein function used earlier, as a list, containing a list of the two similar words.

You might need to trim it down somehow, as I think you'll get all like-combinations twice, i.e. ['word','work'] as one return value, and ['work','word'] as another.

As you develop the code, you could swap in different correlation functions and try different threshold values.